# Convert each integer row to character and string to dates

Tags: r

I am trying to convert the integer in my dataset to individual characters and to dates, with no luck: I tried the following

```
# input data 
elog  <- read.csv("data.csv",sep = ",", as.is = T)
elog[1:3,]

elog$cust <- toString(elog$cust)
elog$date <- toString(elog$date)
elog$date <- as.Date(elog$date, "%Y%m%d");
```

It gives me the following :

Before conversion:

[image]

After conversion:

[image]

The end result I am trying to recreate:

[image]

Comment: don't use `toString`, `as.character` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `as.character`

```
# input data 
elog  <- read.csv("data.csv", sep = ",", as.is = T)
elog[1:3,]

elog$cust <- as.character(elog$cust)
elog$date <- as.character(elog$date)
elog$date <- as.Date(elog$date, "%Y%m%d")
```